# How to get value of clicked item in custom polymer element

Tags: polymer-1.0

Set up:

```
Index.html
  -- custom-obj1.html
  -- custom-obj2.html
```

I have my index.html with an iron-page with two items/pages

custom-obj1: Element that draws a few paper-card elements drawn with a iron-aja a source.

custom-obj2: Same as above but fetching data from ID from clicked element from custom-obj1.

What I'm not sure about here is how to write the event and where to store and read the ID from the first action. Can I data bind clicked id into my second custom element?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a parent element so you can pipe them trough polymer [data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding) with a common [property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties).

So your setup should look like this:

```
Index.html
-- parent-element (property: data)
   -- custom-obj1 (property: data)
   -- custom-obj2 (property: data)
```

So if you change anything in the data binding it will be synchronized trough the parent element.

More information to design apps and thinking in Polymer from Kevin Shaaf (Polymer Summit 2015): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDjiUmx51y8

Of corse you can listen the *`property-name-changed`* event if you add the `notify: true` to it's property and you can give that to anything, but I suggest to use the Polymer Data Binding system.